# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (axios => getData =>setState => .map => return elmItem => error)

Tags: reactjs, axios, typeerror, setstate, array-map

Should I use pagination? Whenever I click this button `<Delete>` its throw out

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Is there any related between

> axios => getData =>setState => .map => return elmItem

Thank you!

```
class ContentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/api/todos")
      .then(res => this.setState({ items: res.data.result }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  handleDelete = value => {
    axios
    .delete(`http://localhost:4000/api/todos/${value}`)
    .then(res => this.setState({items: res.data.result}))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };

  render() {
    let { items } = this.state;
    const elmItem = items.map((item, index) => {
      return <TableComponent item={item} key={index} index={index} handleDelete={this.handleDelete}/>;
    });}
    <table className="table">
          <tbody>{elmItem}</tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: what are you getting in `res.data.result`

Comment: I'm surely understand what i'm getting in axios.delete sir. So the problem is solved a few minutes ago, very thank you! I'm using axios.get after axios.delete to setState the items, now i'm facing the asynchronous's problem, when i'm click delete it doesnt setState, my 2nd Click will make it setState.

Comment: Ensure that you are getting data from **res.data.result** and **res.data.result** must be in the form of array if you want to iterate that data with the map function.

Comment: an example would take me so far sir, could you give me any simple ex please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug your **handleDelete** function with console.log(); in your console browser.

1. Check your value parameter is pass the correct value.
2. Check your response as well.

```
 handleDelete = value => {
    console.log(value); // check paremeter value here
    axios
    .delete(`http://localhost:4000/api/todos/${value}`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.result) // check is data return in the array form so you iterate with the map function.
     this.setState({items: res.data.result})
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
```

To learn more about the axios hit the below link

https://github.com/axios/axios

To understand about the map hit the below link

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html